# Use Numpy to Dynamically Create Arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use numpy to dynamically create a set of zeros based on the size of a separate numpy array.

This is a small portion of the code of a much larger project. I have posted everything relevant in this question. I have a function **k means** which takes in a dataset (posted below) and a k value (which is 3, for this example). 
I create a variable `centroids` which is supposed to look something like

```
[[4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1]
[7.2 3.  5.8 1.6]
[7.2 3.6 6.1 2.5]]
```

From there, I need to create a numpy array of "labels", one corresponding to every row in the dataset, of all zeroes with the same shape as the centroids array. Meaning, for a dataset with 5 rows, it would look like: 
`[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`

This is what I am **trying to** achieve, albiet on a dynamic scale (i.e. where the # of rows and columns in the dataset are unknown).

The following (hard coded, non numpy) satisfies that (assuming there are 150 lines in the dataset:

```
def k_means(dataset, k):
    centroids = [[5,3,2,4.5],[5,3,2,5],[2,2,2,2]]

    cluster_labels = []
    for i in range(0,150):
        cluster_labels.append([0,0,0,0])
    print (cluster_labels)
```

I am trying to do this dynamically with the following:

```
def k_means(dataset, k):
    centroids = dataset[numpy.random.choice(dataset.shape[0], k, replace=False), :]
    print(centroids)

    cluster_labels = []
    cluster_labels = numpy.asarray(cluster_labels)
    for index in range(len(dataset)):
        # temp_array = numpy.zeros_like(centroids)
        # print(temp_array)
        cluster_labels = cluster_labels.append(cluster_labels, numpy.zeros_like(centroids))
```

The current result is: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'` 
Or, if I comment out the `cluster_labels` line and uncomment the temp, I get:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I will ultimately get 150 sets of that.

Sample of Iris Dataset:

```
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
4.9 3   1.4 0.2
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
5   3.6 1.4 0.2
5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3
5   3.4 1.5 0.2
4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2
4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1
5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2
4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2
4.8 3   1.4 0.1
4.3 3   1.1 0.1
5.8 4   1.2 0.2
5.7 4.4 1.5 0.4
5.4 3.9 1.3 0.4
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.3
5.7 3.8 1.7 0.3
5.1 3.8 1.5 0.3
5.4 3.4 1.7 0.2
5.1 3.7 1.5 0.4
4.6 3.6 1   0.2
5.1 3.3 1.7 0.5
4.8 3.4 1.9 0.2
5   3   1.6 0.2
5   3.4 1.6 0.4
5.2 3.5 1.5 0.2
5.2 3.4 1.4 0.2
4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2
4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2
5.4 3.4 1.5 0.4
5.2 4.1 1.5 0.1
5.5 4.2 1.4 0.2
```

Can anybody help me dynamically use numpy to achieve what I am aiming for?

Thanks.

Comment: A list has an `append` method, a numpy array (`ndarray`) does not.  It's best to collect values in a list (the original `cluster_labels`) with list append, and create an array from that afterwards (outside the loop).

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, thank you for that, frankly I did not know the difference. Can you help to draft up a solution that implements your comment?

Comment: @JerryM. What is confusing me in your question is that your desired output for a dataset of 5 rows is `[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`. Shouldn't it be (with `arr = np.zeros_like(centroids`) `[arr, arr, arr, arr, arr]`, a 3D array?

Comment: As I mentioned, the zeros_like does not give me the result I want. I did post my attempt, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shape` of a numpy array is the size of the array. In a 2D array `shape` represents `(number of rows, number of columns)`. So, `shape[0]` is the number of rows and `shape[1]` is the number of columns. You can use `numpy.zeros((dataset.shape[0], centroids.shape[1]))` to create a numpy array with your desired dimensions. Here is an example code with modified version of your `k-means` function.

```
import numpy

def k_means(dataset, k):
    centroids = dataset[numpy.random.choice(dataset.shape[0], k, replace=False), :]
    print(centroids)

    cluster_labels = numpy.zeros((dataset.shape[0], centroids.shape[1]))
    print(cluster_labels)


dataset = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], 
                    [3,4,5,6,4,3,2,2,6,7],
                    [4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,0], 
                    [5,6,7,8,5,3,3,2,2,1],
                    [6,3,3,2,2,4,5,6,6,8]])

k_means(dataset, 2)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]
 [5 6 7 8 5 3 3 2 2 1]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I used `numpy.zeros((dataset.shape[0], centroids.shape[1]))` to make it more similar to your code. Actually, `numpy.zeros(dataset.shape)` would do the same thing, because `centroids.shape[1]` and `dataset.shape[1]` is the same. The number of columns of `centroids` and the number columns `dataset` are the same, because you choose your centroids from the dataset. So, the last version should be like:

```
def k_means(dataset, k):
    centroids = dataset[numpy.random.choice(dataset.shape[0], k, replace=False), :]
    cluster_labels = numpy.zeros(dataset.shape)
```

Comment: Sorry, for this comment. I didn't write something correctly. This answered my question with a good explanation.

Comment: Hi, @Alperen. Is there a difference between `[4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2]
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4]
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4]
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4]
 [4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2]
 [6.8 3.  5.5 2.1]` and `[4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2],
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4],
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4],
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4],
 [4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2],
 [6.8 3.  5.5 2.1]`

Comment: Because of the syntax of Python, you need to use commas while defining the array. Actually, you are defining array of arrays to define 2D array. So, you need commas between items.

Comment: the reason I ask is your solution does not yield commas, however the one that I posted as a "hack fix" did. But yours seems to run with my program?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are talking about printing a numpy array. It is all about the numpy package. I guess, they override `str()` function in numpy package for more understandable print outputs. For example, lets define a list `a=[[1,2],[2,3]]`. If you print it, it will yield `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. If you define it as numpy array `a = numpy.array(a)` and print it, it will yield `[[1 2] [3 4]]` in two rows. Try it yourself.

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb @Alperen, you are correct and that makes sense. I am struggling to grasp this all quickly. Thank you.